# Strange parallel loop behaviour int v long int

Tags: c++, types, integer, openmp

I have some code i'm running in parallel using an OMP for loop, up to large numbers. The code (with unimportant bits removed) is as follows (apologies if it's a mess/hard to follow):

```
long int primePos=-1;
unsigned long long int odd;
int primeFactor;
while(fileNumber<=nFiles)
{
    percPrev=0;
    compCounter=0;
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(numberElements, iStart, iEnd,tau, wall0) schedule (guided) private(primePos,odd,primeFactor)
    for(unsigned long long int i=iStart;i<=iEnd;i++){
        #pragma omp atomic
        tau++;

        odd=2*i-1;
        if(!IsPrime(odd)){
            primeFactor = getPrimeFactor(odd);
            for(long int j=0;j<PrimeDatL;j++){
                if(PrimeDataT[j]==primeFactor){
                    primePos=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            #pragma omp critical 
            {   
                if(compCounter+1>numberElements){
                    cout<<"Array overflow, exiting."<<endl;
                    exit(0);
                }
                InsertElement(odd,primeFactor,pHVector,primePos);
                compCounter++;
            }
        }           
    }   
iStart=iEnd+1;
iEnd=min(iEnd+numberElements,maxVal);
fileNumber++;
}
```

The idea is that I go through all the odds up to `2^n`, if they're not prime I take the smallest prime factor and put it, along with the odd, in a vector which is arranged in a particular fashion. The variable `primePos` simply denotes which spot in this vector it goes into, and isn't a particularly large number so it was originally simply an `int` type.

However, for larger values of n ~33, I found that InsertElement() was throwing an exception because `primePos` was huge, much larger than it could possibly be as defined in the for loop which searches for the position of `primeFactor` in `PrimeDataT`. This was rectified (well, it compiles and runs and for low values of n i can verify in mathematica that it's correct) by changing `primePos` from `int` to `long int`, but i've no idea why that should be the case and I'd like to know before I continue, in case I'm missing something important.

tl;dr = how can primePos take a value larger than PrimeDatL if it is declared as an `int` instead of `long int`?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `2^33` doesn't fit in an `int` on most systems. There's probably an overflow problem.

Comment: what platform are you on. IN some cases int is the same as long int some times not

Answer (score 0):

Once a  `int` reaches a value greater then 2,147,483,647, it will begin to count "up" from -2,147,483,648 a `int` is simply 32 bits and cannot be larger than half that to account for negative values.

If the problem you are having is that your primePos is being set to a number like 2^33 you may have to create a new way to find the position.

hope that helps
-J

Comment: Hi J (and others)

Sorry, I should have clarified the variables:

odds will be the very large number
primePos<PrimeDatL will NOT be very large ( PrimeDatL is essentially the number of primes less than 2^n, which is much much less than odds which is the number of non-prime odd numbers less than 2^n)

For instance, for n = 33, PrimeDatL is only about 9000 (according to the prime algorithm i pinched from someone else on this forum, which may indeed be a source of error if i am misusing it/going beyond its scope)

Comment: Would you happen to be able to link to that algorithm, it sounds like you're trying to use Eratosthenes algorithm for finding primes.       [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: I'm using the code from this post:
http://tinyurl.com/kcdckmy

I doubt it is the problem though (unless it's causing some complex knock-on effect) as Mathematica gives the same number of primes for n = 33 as my code, so PrimeData array I think is correct, it's something funny going on with the `PrimePos` counter itself (which merely counts over elements in `PrimeData`). Basically the issue is that when i set primePos = j, it still sometimes returns `primePos`> `PrimeDatL`, despite j only looping up TO `PrimeDatL` (unless I use long int instead of int, which really should make no difference)